# Prove or disprove cross product is distributive. Is this problem valid?

Tags: abstract-algebra, vectors

Prove or disprove cross product is distributive. Is this problem valid? This is likely a very popular problem, I just read it in Griffiths' *Intoduction to Electrodynamics*, 3ed, page 4, problem 1.1. However I am confused what it is they're asking.

Distributive with respect to addition? Distributive with respect to dot product? Distributive with respect to scalar multiplication? I think they mean the first one, but isn't the author being sloppy? If I want to be thorough I'd consider every option I can think of because the question seems ambiguous. Or is there some kind of convention I am supposed to follow?

Comment: Just write out the formula for cross product and you can easily verify them.

Comment: "Distributive with respect to dot product" doesn't type-check, since $a \times (b \cdot c)$ is the cross product of a scalar and a vector. Neither does it make sense to say "distributive with respect to scalar multiplication" - that also doesn't type check.

Comment: Isn't it vacuously true, though?

Comment: Distributivity is usually over addition. That is, you shall show that $a\times(b+c)=a\times b+a\times c$ and $(a+b)\times c=a\times c+b\times c$ (for all $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}^3$).

Comment: Why should it be vacuously true?

Comment: Is the word "usually" part of mathematical terminology?

Comment: @Peter. No, that's just English.

Answer (score 1):

> Prove or disprove cross product is distributive.

Whether this question is „valid“ or „invalid“ depends on who you ask and largely depends on one's own definition of validity.  I can answer a more precise question:

> What context could have been added to this question to make it unambiguous?

### Short answer

It is very very likely that the question means

> Decide whether the cross product (in $ℝ³$) distributes over vector addition in $ℝ³$.

Why over vector addition? Well, distributivity is a property that describes the  interplay between an abstract operation called „addition“ and an abstract operation called „multiplication“.  In this case, since we talk about the cross *product*, this suggests that the cross product $ℝ³×ℝ³→ℝ³$ is to be taken as the multiplication.  The only thing that I know under the name „addition“ in this context is vector addition.

### Context

More generally, if we have a set $S$ and two operations $+: S×S→S$, $\cdot: S×S→S$, we call the three things $(S, +, ×)$ a *commutative ring* if it satisfies the following conditions:

- $+$ behaves „like an addition“, i.e. $(S, +)$ is an abelian group whose neutral element we will call $0$
- $+$ behaves „like a multiplication“, i.e. $(S, \cdot)$ is a monoid whose neutral element we will call $1$
- *(this is the distributivity property!)* for all elements $x, y, z\in S$, we have $x\cdot (y+z) = x\cdot y+x\cdot z$ and $(y+z)\cdot x = y\cdot x+z\cdot x$

---

Could the question have been stated more explicitly? certainly.

Would it have helped if you provided the precise quote and a reference for the statement in question, so we can find it and see the context? Probably also yes ;)

Comment: The distributive law usually applies to some kind of multiplication over some kind of addition, but there are other cases. In Boolean algebras one has both the ordinary $x(y+z)=xy+xz$ but also the other way around: $x+yz=(x+y)(x+z),$ i.e. addition is distributive over multiplication.

Comment: Not quite, you're talking about boolean _rings_ (which can be associated to boolean algebras). A boolean algebra would be a complemented distributive lattice $(L, 0, 1, \wedge, \vee)$. But yes.

Comment: I think the issue with problems like this one is that the author makes the assumption that the reader never heard the word "distributive" before and is not expected to explore the subject much further in the future. And what prevents one from defining an algebra with ten different operations with some of them being distributive over others.

Comment: They could at least write something like "in this book we will use this definition because it serves our purpose". "In other applications you may encounter a slightly different approach".

Answer (score 1):

On the previous pages, Griffiths says:

> The dot product is *commutative*, $$ \mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{B} = \mathbf{B} \cdot \mathbf{A},$$and *distributive*, $$ \mathbf{A} \cdot (\mathbf{B} + \mathbf{C}) = \mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{B} + \mathbf{A} \cdot \mathbf{C}, \tag{1.2}$$
>
> ...
>
> The cross product is *distributive*,
> $$ \mathbf{A} \times (\mathbf{B} + \mathbf{C}) = (\mathbf{A} \times \mathbf{B}) + (\mathbf{A} \times \mathbf{C}), \tag{1.5}$$
> but *not commutative.*

The question you're asking about immediately follows this section:

> **Problem 1.1** Using the definitions in Eqs. (1.1) and (1.4), and appropriate diagrams, show that the dot product and cross product are distributive.

From this context, it seems fairly obvious that whenever Griffiths says "distributive", he implicitly means "over addition".

---

<sub>For the record, Eqs. (1.1) and (1.4) give the formulas for the dot product and cross product in terms of the vectors' mangitudes, the angle between them, and (in the case of the cross product) a unit vector at right angles to both.</sub>